# Proof that an almost complete binary tree with n nodes has at least $\frac{n}{2}$ leaf nodes

Tags: data-structures, proof-techniques, binary-trees

I'm having some trouble proving what my title states. Some textbooks refer to almost complete binary trees as complete, so to make myself clear, when I say almost complete binary tree I mean a binary tree whose levels are all full except for the last one in which all the nodes are as far left as possible.

I thought of proving it using induction but I'm not really sure how to do so. Any ideas?

*UPDATE*

Well I made somewhat of a progress but I also got a somewhat different result, here's what I did:

Let $T$ be an almost complete tree of height $h$ meaning that in the level of height $h$ there should be at least 1 node. Considering the fact that every height has double the number of nodes of the previous level we can derive that $T$ has the least possible number of nodes in the case that at $h$-level there is only one node. **(1)**

In that case the number of leaf nodes is

$l=2^{h-1}-1+1 \Rightarrow l=2^{h-1}$ and the number of total nodes is

$n=2^{h-1}-1+1$

$\Rightarrow l=2^{h-1}=\frac{2(2^{h-1}+1)}{2}=\frac{n+1}{2}$

$\xrightarrow{(1)(2)} l \geq\frac{n+1}{2}$

Now, I'm getting a bit closer but not really there yet. First problem is that I got $l \geq \frac{n+1}{2}$ and not $l \geq \frac{n}{2}$ which from what I understand stands only in the specific case that $h=1$. Second problem is that this doesn't seem like a formal proof... Any tips/suggestions?

Comment: Hint, try proving the stronger claim that there are $\lceil n/2\rceil$ leaf nodes.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment, but I couldn't really see how it could help me. Anyway I updated my post so maybe you can check if I'm getting closer, thnks again

Comment: You are almost there, although there are a few typos in your calculation. If you have shown $l\ge \frac{n+1}2$, then you have shown $l\ge\frac n2$. To go further, you can suppose there are $x$ nodes in the level of height $h$, where $1\le x\le2^h$

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees) Wikipedia page:

> In a *complete* binary tree every level, except possibly the last, is completely filled, and all nodes in the last level are as far left as possible. It can have between $1$ and $2^h$ nodes at the last level $h$. An alternative definition is a *perfect* tree whose rightmost leaves (perhaps all) have been removed. Some authors use the term *complete* to refer instead to a *perfect* binary tree as defined below, in which case they call this type of tree (with a possibly not filled last level) an *almost complete* binary tree or *nearly complete* binary tree...

So, you are talking about a binary tree with $h$ levels, for which all levels  with numbers $k \in [0,h-1]$ are completely filled up (i.e. have $2^k$ nodes), and the level $h$ is potentially incomplete - it contains $(2^h-r)$ nodes, where $r \in [0, 2^h-1]$ is the number of (rightmost) removed nodes. Total number of nodes of such tree is $(2^{h+1}-r-1)$. Let's find the number of leaves for this tree.

If $r$ is even, then the removal of $r$ nodes on the level $h$ will give you $\frac{r}{2}$ new leaves. So, the total number $l_{even}$ of leaves will be:

$$l_{even}=2^h - r + \frac{r}{2} = 2^h - \frac{r}{2}$$

if $r$ is odd, then the removal of $r$ nodes on the level $h$ will give you $\frac{r+1}{2}$ new leaves. So, the total number $l_{odd}$ of leaves will be:

$$l_{odd}=2^h-r+\frac{r+1}{2}=2^h-\frac{r-1}{2}$$

Now you'll be able to verify, that in both cases:

$$l \ge \frac{2^{h+1}-r-1}{2}$$

Comment: Pretty nice write-up.